# How to execute my code using terminal without terminal being occupied

Tags: command-line, python, python3, process

Guys you might think this is a coding issue but there is a strong possibility that I wouldn't need to entirely modify my code to solve this problem.

So I've written a headless(without GUI) music player using python and I am currently executing it like this:
`python3 main.py`
I can pause/unpause the running track from inside the program.
but the terminal is occupied , I have to let this extra terminal remain open while I am doing whatever I'm doing and It's kind of bugging me.

How I interact my program now:
*the terminal is occupied so I should terminate my program to free it*

```
:~$python3 main.py
playing track0.mp3: pause 
paused track0.mp3: quit
:~$ls #I terminated the program so I could do this in currently running terminal
```

How I want to interact with my program:the terminal is NOT occupied so I can run other stuff in it.

```
:~$python3 main.py -init #It should not open the program in terminal
:~$ls #so I can do this while the music is playing
:~$python3 main.py pause #and like this I pause the program
:~$nano ~/.bashrc #and again I can use my terminal 
:~$python3 main.py quit #and like this I terminate my program
```

I know it's possible I just don't know how.

Edit:
A person said you should publish your code so we can help you
so : https://github.com/yolowex/odd-musicplayer

Comment: You are right . I am adding the source code to my git.

Comment: You can try running your program inside `screen`, then detach the `screen` session (Ctrl-A then D). Whenever you want to return to your program, you can re-attach the `screen` session (`screen -r`). Or simply open two `screen` windows and switch between them. Check the `screen` manual: https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Answer (score 3):

You should realize that the Linux terminal (bash) is capable of multitasking, so the terminal is never truly "occupied". By default you can suspend a running program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (sending `stty susp`).

But it can be even simpler to run the script in the background.

```
python3 main.py &
```

You can then later give it foreground focus with the `fg` command. This is basic [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html).

If you additionally want to run the script so it isn't attached to the current terminal (and doesn't exit when you close it), use the `nohup` command:

```
nohup python3 main.py &
```

Comment: I tried & / disown and nohup but none of them seem to work. exactly nothing happens. I think this is because my code includes input commands and a thread so it is a bit trickey. to exit the program properly I even needed to use thread.daemon so the thread is killed after terminating the program. I also tried ```Ctrl```+```Z```

Comment: Ok, in that case [so] is the right place to ask.